# How to compare lists of different types

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, hashmap

I have two lists. One list has 6 elements, another one has 3 elements. I need compare both the lists and retain only that information in the aList which matches bList.

```
public class AClass{

    String cname;
    int cid;
    int aid;
}

public class BClass{
    String cname;
    int sc_id;
    int aid;
}
```

And the two lists:

```
List<AClass> aList;
List<BClass> bList;
```

For example, aList has 1,2,3,4,5,6 and bList has 1,4,5. The comparison has to be done so that aList has 1,4,5 in it.

I've tried the below code. But doesn't work.

```
aList.retainAll(bList);
```

Kindly help!

Comment: What do you want to compare?

Comment: Have you tried mapping all objects in ```bList``` to an ```AClass``` object? Then compare ```aList``` against this new list that you've created.

Comment: When you say `aList has 1,2,3,4,5,6` what exactly do you mean? Because your classes contain more than just a single integer.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS aList 1,2,3,4,5,6 refers to cid. Both the lists have a common field. cid of aList is same as sc_id of bList

Comment: @MuratKaragöz i want to compare the ids(cid of aList with sc_id of bList) in both the lists, and retain only the information that matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the idea is to compare every element of `aList` with every element of `bList` while comparing `sc_id == e.cid`. You can use streams for that. Looks like this

```
aList = aList.stream().filter(e -> bList.stream().anyMatch(b -> b.sc_id == e.cid)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the ids you want to keep first, then filter against them.

```
Set<Integer> keepIds = bList.stream().map(BClass:getId).collect(toSet());
List<AClass> filtered = aList.stream
                             .filter(a -> keepIds.contains(a.getId()))
                             .collect(toList());
```

Answer (score -1):

```
List<Integer> a = List.of(1,2,3,4,5);
List<Integer> b = List.of(1,4,6);
List<Integer> collect = a.stream().filter(b::contains).collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(collect);
```

Comment: He does not have a List of Integers.